# Why am I suffering extreme lag on any multiplayer server in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Since yesterday, I have been suffering extreme lag on *any* multiplayer server in Minecraft. Whenever I join a server, my chat messages won't show up, everyone else is frozen, and the world is not fully loaded. After about 2 minutes, it says "Connection lost. Timed out", and I get kicked from the server. This  has happened for all of the servers I play on. Why am I suffering extreme lag in Multiplayer? How should I fix this?

(My Minecraft is on Ubuntu 14.04, if that's helpful)

Thank you.

Test results (as suggested by @Rainbolt):

Pingtest.net - Grade: D*, Ping: 164 MS, Jitter: 51 ms

Speedtest.net - Ping: 37 MS, Download speed: 3.06 Mbps, Upload speed: 0.54 Mbps

Comment: Do other multiplayer games work fine? Because this sounds like a slow internet connection. are all ports unblocked you need to connect to the servers?

Comment: @JonasDralle If the ports were blocked, he wouldn't be able to connect at all (you can't lose a connection you never had).

Comment: @RobertL Go to http://www.speedtest.net/ and run a test. Take a screenshot of the results and add it to your question. Then do the same for http://www.pingtest.net/. Then get the model of your router and add that to your question. Identify whether you are on a wireless connection or a wired connection. If wireless, what model is your wireless card? Googling this exact error returns tons of results. Have you visited any of those links and tried *anything* at all? If so, what were the results?

Comment: I just saw your edit. Was the packet loss blank on the ping test?

Answer (score 6):

The following are possible points of failure:

- You
- Your machine
- Your router
- Your ISP
- The Server's ISP
- The Server's router
- The Server machine

**Step 1**

Connect to other servers. Do you experience the same problem on every server? If not, then the server has issues and there isn't much you can do about it. If so, continue to step 2.

Congratulations! You have already completed this step. You mentioned in the question that you have the same problem across multiple servers.

**Step 2**

Host a server on another machine on your network and connect to it via LAN. Does it work? If so, your router, your machine, and you are not the problem, and you should blame your ISP. If not, continue to step 3.

**Step 3**

[Monitor the memory usage](https://askubuntu.com/a/138685) just before, during, and after you lose connection. Is the amount of memory used close to the amount of memory you have available? If so, then the game is stuttering because of constant memory swapping, and you need more RAM. I'm not sure if this can actually cause disconnections, but it can cause extreme lag. If not, continue to step 4.

**Step 4**

Are you on a wireless connection? If so, find an Ethernet cable and plug directly into your router. Did that fix your problem? If so, then the problem is your wireless card. If not, continue to Step 5.

**Step 5**

Buy a new router from a store that has a lenient return policy. Install it. Did that fix your problem? If so, then the problem is your router. If not, get your money back and continue to Step 6.

There is no step 6. I am out of ideas, but if you comment on the post with your *extremely detailed* results from following the steps above, I might suddenly have more ideas.